# Learning Java Recursion, Ackerman function

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working on a recursive [Ackermann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) function in Java. I am getting an error at may recursive line, 23.

> ```
> return Ack(m - 1, Ack(m, n - 1));
> ```

Thanks so much if anyone could point out what's wrong.

-Kyle

```
   /*enter code here

     Ackerman's function, A(m, n) is defined:
     A(0 , n) = n + 1 for n  >= 0 
     A(m , 0) = A(m – 1 , 1) for m > 0
     A(m , n) = A(m – 1 , A(m , n - 1)) for n >= 0

    */

    public class AckFun {

     public static int Ack(int m, int n) {

      if (m == 0) {
       return 2 * n;
      } else if (m >= 1) {
       if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
       } else if (n == 1) {
        return 2;
       } else {
        return Ack(m - 1, Ack(m, n - 1));
       }
      }
      return n; // Not sure what to return here, Eclipse suggested this.
     }

     public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println(Ack(3, 4));
     }
    }
```

Comment: Well the reason Eclipse requires the "return n" is because otherwise you'd have a section that doesn't return anything.

your method is of the form:
if (a) else if (b) ... but if neither a or b is true, then you end up outside of either block.

Comment: I like that it's **java.lang.StackOverflowError**

Comment: additional point, Java's methods names start with lowercase. It should be `public static int ack( int m, in n )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make your stack larger:

http://thilinamb.wordpress.com/2008/12/22/how-to-increase-the-java-stack-size/

With larger stack it runs without stackoverflow, but gives 0.

EDIT: Your code is wrong, that is why it gives the error. Try to rewrite the code exactly as the definition says:

```
    //I assume that you check that n and m are non-negative before you run this
    if (m == 0) {
         return n + 1;
    } else if (n == 0) {
        return Ack(m - 1, 1);
    } else {
        return Ack(m - 1, Ack(m, n - 1));
    }
```

PS. Don't blame me for posting source code for homework problems. I believe that the best way to learn programming is by reading and understanding someone else's code.

Comment: I think something else may be wrong, I think the answer should be 125 for the values (3, 4), small enough to not need the larger stack treatment (yet).

Answer (score 3):

You've exceeded the maximum recursion depth. That's one of the features of the Ackermann function. :)

If you call it with smaller numbers, like `Ack(3,3)`, then it doesn't overflow the stack.

It's possible to increase Java's recursion depth limit, but that's not necessarily a good solution. This may be an exercise in transforming the program so that it doesn't use Java's built-in call stack, but keeps track of each call in a data structure (perhaps a Stack). You can also use memoization, where you record the result of the function call so you don't have to compute the same result over and over.

Comment: Really, the correct output for (3, 3) is 65536.
I thought that for (3, 4) it should be 125.
?

Answer (score 1):

With a return in front, you don't need 'else'.

```
if (m == 0)    return n + 1;
if (n == 0)    return ack (m - 1, 1);
return ack (m - 1, ack (m, n - 1));
```